# External ID matching no longer an option in Data Import Wizard for custom object to add new records

Tags: externalid, data-import-wizard

Every week we do a import into SF. The sales team reported they cannot add records to the custom object by matching external ID anymore. I checked and they are correct. previously we were doing it through this route go to custom object > contracts > add new > match by: external ID.

Now all we see is "match by: name".

Has anyone else had this issue and how did you resolve?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your External ID is set to Unique and you will be able to match by it using the import wizard!

Answer (score 0):

See if the below from the Salesforce Help doesn't solve your issue:

> **Map your data fields to Salesforce data fields.**
>
> - The Data Import wizard maps as many of your data fields as possible to standard Salesforce data fields. But if the wizard can’t map fields, you must do it manually. Unmapped fields are not imported into Salesforce.
> - To see a list of standard Salesforce data fields, from the management settings for the object, go to the fields area.
> - Scan the list of mapped data fields and locate the unmapped fields.
> - Click Map to the left of each unmapped field.
> - In the Map Your Field dialog box, choose the Salesforce fields you want to map to and click Map.
>
> **Note:** The Map Your Field dialog box also gives you the option of saving data from unmapped fields in a general notes field for accounts and contacts. To do so, choose Account Note or Contact Note from the Map To drop-down list and click Map.